# One day less than original date while uploading data in salesforce

Tags: date, csv

I am importing data via a CSV file. In CSV file the date is 15/08/2015(dd/mm/yyyy) but when i check it in salesforce it is 14/08/2015(dd/mm/yyyy). The date is always one day less than original date. I am not uploading data with code not by data loader. What should i do?

Comment: If the date is ending up in a DateTime field, the problem is likely to be caused by your timezone offset. Using a Date field avoids that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you specify the timezone when importing date/time fields.

You can read more about this here:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004680&